# Box.com api file copy file source?

Tags: c#, box

I'm using the Box.com SDK for file management. I'm looking at the file copy function and I'll be danged if I can figure out how to specify the source file for the copy. I've looked in the SDK code and at the get calls in their documentation and each time it just specifies where the new file should go but I see no explicit way to specify what the source file is for the SDK (although I can see how in the post/get manual calls).

Am I going crazy or perhaps missing something really simple?

Example Code from their SDK:

```
        BoxFileRequest request = new BoxFileRequest()
        {
            Name = "test",
            Parent = new BoxRequestEntity() { Id = "0" }
        };

        /*** Act ***/
        BoxFile f = await _filesManager.CopyAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.Id` must be the source file's id.

`Name` would be the copy's filename.

`Parent.Id` is the folder for the copy.

Doc of API function: https://box-content.readme.io/reference#copy-a-file

The `CopyAsync` function: https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2/blob/master/Box.V2/Managers/BoxFilesManager.cs#L224

Comment: `request.Id` is what I was missing. Thanks. I'm using the sdk code you linked to to make my calls to simplify our own calls through the FilesManager. How are you seeing that `request.Id` is the target file?

Comment: From the API doc, the url has to be _/files/FILE_ID/copy_ and from the source code: `new BoxRequest(_config.FilesEndpointUri, string.Format(Constants.CopyPathString, fileRequest.Id))`. And also from the code, `Constants.CopyPathString = @"{0}/copy"`. So fileRequest.Id has to be the source file id.

Comment: I see it now. That's a bit convoluted although I can see why. Thanks for the explanation.